# Procedural material to mesh using displacement

Tags: displacement

I can't for the life of me figure out how to use a procedural material I created to create a mesh. I created a landscape based off this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrMee2gcS20

I am using the procedural material to mesh generation instructions from a second tutorial and my results are not turning out the same at all: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McALCOr39rY

My blend file can be downloaded here: 
https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZB34MkZ8ub1bCcxmohP97mJhlIKJu3iOgSV

I see that in the second tutorial, the guy is using a multiply node at the end, but a multiply node was not used in the first tutorial.

Please help! What am I doing wrong here? THANK YOU!

Comment: The correct way is the first video's way, the "Displacement" node wasn't present in blender from the start and you had to use the multiply node to control the displacement output. Where exactly are you stuck ? At which step ?

Comment: Well the second video is the only way I can get the material to bake out to a mesh; the first video always ends up with a black texture when I try baking it

Comment: Can you try downloading my file and baking the landscape into a mesh? And see why it isn't working?